# Cómo abrir una nueva activity al ingresar 3 veces erróneo el patrón de bloqueo

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando un proyecto en Android Studio (Java) para mi tesis, pero lo que necesito ahora es solucionar un problema con el patrón de bloqueo.

Me estoy poniendo en la posición de que un usuario ingrese 3 intentos fallidos el patrón, por lo que me gustaría que al momento de que coloque 3 veces erróneo el patrón lo envíe a otra activity (aun no la creo).

Por el momento mi patrón funciona impecable al momento de guardar y al momento de iniciar, solo me falta validar que detecte los 3 intentos fallidos. No sé si me explique bien.

Dejo a continuación el código de cuando creo por primera vez (`guardarpatron.java`) y también el que inicio sesión (`principalpatron.java`)

**guardarpatron**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andrognito.patternlockview.PatternLockView;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.listener.PatternLockViewListener;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.utils.PatternLockUtils;

import java.util.List;

import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class GuardarPatron extends AppCompatActivity {

    String save_pattern_key = "pattern_codigo";
    String final_pattern = "";
    PatternLockView mPatternLockView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guardar_patron);

        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.appbar_background));

        Paper.init(this);
        final String save_pattern = Paper.book().read(save_pattern_key);
        if(save_pattern != null && !save_pattern.equals("null"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal_patron);
            mPatternLockView = (PatternLockView)findViewById(R.id.pattern_lock_view);
            mPatternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(List<PatternLockView.Dot> progressPattern) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> pattern) {
                    final_pattern = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(mPatternLockView,pattern);
                    if(final_pattern.equals(save_pattern)){
                        Toast.makeText(GuardarPatron.this, "El patron es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(GuardarPatron.this,Splash.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }else{ Toast.makeText(GuardarPatron.this, "Error! Intenta otra vez!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


                }

                @Override
                public void onCleared() {

                }
            });
        }
        else
        {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_guardar_patron);
            mPatternLockView = (PatternLockView)findViewById(R.id.pattern_lock_view);
            mPatternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(List<PatternLockView.Dot> progressPattern) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> pattern) {
                    final_pattern = PatternLockUtils .patternToString(mPatternLockView,pattern);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCleared() {

                }
            });




            Button btnSetup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetearPatron);
            btnSetup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Paper.book().write(save_pattern_key, final_pattern);
                    Toast.makeText(GuardarPatron.this, "Su patron se ha guardado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GuardarPatron.this, PrincipalPatron.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**principalpatron**

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.andrognito.patternlockview.PatternLockView;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.listener.PatternLockViewListener;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.utils.PatternLockUtils;

import java.util.List;

import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class PrincipalPatron extends AppCompatActivity {


    String save_pattern_key = "pattern_codigo";
    PatternLockView mPatternLockView;
    String final_pattern = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Paper.init(this);

        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.appbar_background));

        final String save_pattern = Paper.book().read(save_pattern_key);
        if(save_pattern != null && !save_pattern.equals("null"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal_patron);
            mPatternLockView = (PatternLockView)findViewById(R.id.pattern_lock_view);
            mPatternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStarted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(List<PatternLockView.Dot> progressPattern) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> pattern) {
                    final_pattern = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(mPatternLockView,pattern);
                    if(final_pattern.equals(save_pattern)){
                        Toast.makeText(PrincipalPatron.this, "El patron es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalPatron.this,Splash.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }else{ Toast.makeText(PrincipalPatron.this, "Error! Intenta otra vez!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


                }

                @Override
                public void onCleared() {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir una variable la cual incrementarias, al incrementarse en 3 ocasiones validas para enviar a la Activity que deseas.

```
          private int counter = 0;
          ...
          ...
          ...
           @Override
                public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> pattern) {
                    final_pattern = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(mPatternLockView,pattern);
                    if(final_pattern.equals(save_pattern)){
                        Toast.makeText(PrincipalPatron.this, "El patron es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalPatron.this,Splash.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }else{ 
                   
                      if(counter > 3){//Revisa si contador es mayor que 3

                       //Envia a Activity de error 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalPatron.this, ActivityError.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                      }else{ 
                         Toast.makeText(PrincipalPatron.this, "Error! Intenta otra vez!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      
                      }
                      counter++; //Incrementa contador.

                    }


                }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, el único detalle que envía a la otra activity cuando llega al quinto patrón erróneo pero es un detalle menor. soluciono mi duda inmediatamente. Muchas gracias.